# How to use the same ref between child/parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to control the carousel in the child component from the parent component.

I have used forward ref on the child component but its not working. Where am I going wrong?

**Parent:**

```
const CoachingCarousel = ({}) => {
  const carouselRef = useRef<Lottie>(null);

  const renderItem = ({item}: any) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.renderItemContainer}>
        {item.icon}
        <Text style={[styles.titletext, spacing.gbMt7]} variant="titleLarge">
          {item.title}
        </Text>
        <Text style={[styles.subtitleText, spacing.gbMt4]} variant="bodyMedium">
          {item.text}
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={[styles.next]}
          variant="bodyLarge"
          onPress={() =>
            carouselRef?.current?.goToSlide(
              totalSlides !== item.key
                ? item.key
                : () => {
                    setCoachingScreenCompleted('CoachingScreenCompleted', true),
                      console.log('Go to homepage');
                  },
            )
          }>
          {totalSlides !== item.key ? 'Next tbc' : 'Done tbc'}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <AppCarousel slides={slides} renderItem={renderItem} ref={carouselRef} />
  );
};
```

**Child:**

```
const AppCarousel = React.forwardRef(
  ({style, slides, renderItem}: props, ref) => {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, style]}>
        <AppIntroSlider
          ref={ref}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          data={slides}
        />
      </View>
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: can you brief your query in order to help you?

Answer (score 0):

### Here a is React rule,

**1.** Do not declare components within other components, this will lead to very weird behaviors in React.

**2.** Also you cannot share ref between two components **at the same time** whether they are parent/child or siblings.

### Answer

Also from what I am seeing, you are using a `ref` to keep track of the current slide. `ref` does not rerender in React so you will not see your changes. Try using `useState`.

[`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) is for non rerendering values or to keep track of DOM nodes which is not necessary in your case.

I found this [tutorial](https://medium.com/tinyso/how-to-create-the-responsive-and-swipeable-carousel-slider-component-in-react-99f433364aa0) to be quite well. One critic would be the over complicated use of `React.children.map` and `React.children.clone` although they have their use cases.

Comment: About the rule 1. in his example it is render prop, not a component. I think AppIntroSlider uses useImperativeHandle, so ref should be OK. But it needs more info to be solved.

Comment: The code is working now! Not sure what happend there... lol